# How can I view all event handlers attached to an element in firebug?

Tags: javascript, dom, firebug

Is it possible to view event handlers attached to an HTML element (e.g. `<a>`) using Firebug or some Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

yes.

http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/eventbug-alpha-released/